# Android - Skewed button

Tags: android, animation, transformation

is it possible to create a skewed shape button?
(i.e like a stripe shape from bottom left of screen to top right of screen instead of the regular square or rectangle shape button)?

Something like this image http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverLightFAQPart2/9.JPG
And I need to make sure the clickable area is also just the colored one.

Thanks,

Tee

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write your own class for that.  Just subclass View and listen for the onClick events.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a selector as background.

```
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:background="@drawable/my_button" 
    />
```

And then make a **my_button.xml** in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedpressed" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" /> 
</selector>
```

Source: http://www.anddev.org/tinytutcustom_button_backgrounds-better_imagebutton-t4298.html